# Is the data stored with jquery's data method removed when the element is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens to the data stored for a given element using the jQuery.data() function after that element is removed or replaced? In tests it appears this data is no longer available after the element it was attached to is removed.

Comment: Hey, good question! +1. Nothing in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ one would probably have to look into the source code.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, when an element is removed by [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on a parent (or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on a parent), the data (stored in the `jQuery.cache` object) is cleaned up as well.

You can see in the source:

- [Here's where it happens for `.remove()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L158-159)
- [Here's where it happens for `.empty()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L175)
- [Here's where it happens for `.html()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L244)

In all these cases, the [`jQuery.cleanData()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L556-592) function does the work.

---

In case others finding this are looking for ways to directly remove data, there are functions for this, just not commonly used directly: [`.removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) and [`$.removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/).  They behave like [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) in usage - without the data key (name parameter) they'll clear all data values for the element.

Comment: Does this hold true also for inlying elements? Like when I empty a container, does the data for all children get cleaned up as well?

Comment: @Pekka - yup, it does a `getElementsByTagName("*")` to grab all children

Comment: and if an element is removed by a direct DOM call, the data actually remains in the jQuery cache but is indeed "removed" from the element, since it won't ever be reused even if the exact same element is created again later, correct?

Comment: @Frédéric - mm kinda, depends how you look at it.  All that's stored on the element is a single attribute, the `$.expando` attribute - it's a key that should be unique - it's the element's entry in `$.cache`, so for example `$.cache[myDomElement[$.expando]]` is that element's data entry...if a new element has that expando property added back, it would show as having data...but that would be rare to do unintentionally.  Any element you just created wouldn't have the same expando attribute key (the `$.uuid`), so it would have a separate  `$.cache` entry.

Comment: I've discovered this occurs if you use replaceAll, also. It's frustrating and should be in the documentation.